# Cannot re-open a popup in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, activex, window.open

I have a piece of code which works perfectly in Chrome. By clicking on the button, it opens a popup by `window.open`, we could close the popup manually, then we can re-open a popup by clicking again on the button:

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/tupiyukixe/edit?html,js,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="contentCtrl">
    <button ng-click="openNew()">New</button>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
      app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.openNew = function () {
          openPopup("https://www.stackoverflow.com")
        }

        function openPopup(url) {
          console.log("openPopup");
          console.log($scope.popup);
          console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.popup))
          if (($scope.popup === null) || ($scope.popup === undefined) || ($scope.popup.location === undefined) || ($scope.popup.location.href === undefined)) {
            $scope.popup = window.open(url, "popup", "status=1, location=1, width=1000, height=1200, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
          } else {
            $scope.popup.location.href = url;
          }
        }
      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, this code does not work in IE 11: we could open a popup for the first time, then after closing manually the popup, clicking on the button leads to nothing.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Your code worked for me in IE11. Have you allowed the popup to allow active x controls?

Comment: Should I do something in my code or in the setting of IE? I just enabled **everything** under `ActiveX controls and plug-ins`, but it still does not work.

Comment: Not your code, but only IE. Is there anything on the debugger console of IE?

Comment: there is nothing displayed in the console of F12...